# How to smooth a 3D graph

Tags: 3d, matplotlib, ipython

I am ploting a 3D graph and i would like to smooth it, 
i tried this syntax :

```py
X, Y = meshgrid(gammas, psis) 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, x,rstride=1.14, cstride=1.14)
plt.show()
ax.view_init(30, 45)
xnew = linspace(x.min(),x.max(),300)
power_smooth1=spline(X,x,xnew)
power_smooth1=spline(Y,x,xnew)
```

I have this error : object too deep for desired array

Comment: which library is this?